# Nikto giving incoherent results

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, nikto

I'm running a scan with Nikto. The command I'm running is pretty simple:

```
nikto -h 192.168.1.15 -p 5050
```

It's a Node.js server. But I get a gazillion vulnerabilitites, for instance:

> OSVDB-19947: /apps/web/index.fcgi?servers=&section=alert(document.cookie): Zeus Admin server 4.1r2 is vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting (XSS).

It does not make sense. I even get ASP vulnerabilities! What am I doing wrong with Nikto here?

Here is a screenshot (the log is too long to be posted here):

[image: Screenshot of Nikto output.]

Comment: False positives are a common problem.  You should check the logs to see exactly what network request it is making, and what response it is receiving.  If you can post the exact HTTP request and response, you'll get much better chances of getting an answer.  Otherwise it's a guessing game.

Comment: @ConorMancone Please see the updated post

Comment: Screenshots are not very helpful.  Still, it wasn't the logs I was looking for, but rather the HTTP response to your example request.  In other words, perform that HTTP request yourself (`/apps/web/index.fcgi?servers=&section=alert(document.cookie)`) and show us what the response is.

Answer (score 1):

Is the node server returning `HTTP 200 OK` for all the requests? 
It looks like your scanner is going though a bunch of known vulnerable urls, if you server is returning `200` for these urls (or redirects to `200` pages) this might be the issue.

Comment: Indeed, it clearly has a list of URLs to check.  Your comment will be especially accurate if the node server does something like print out its input (which is a terrible idea in production, but a not-uncommon thing to do when first testing a new technology).  In that case, the server would actually have a valid XSS vulnerability on literally every page.  This might explain what is going on if nikto is looking for more than just a simple 200 to determine the existence of a vulnerable endpoint.  Unfortunately it's hard to say without an actual HTTP request/response.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common scenario with nikto where the webserver responds in a way that makes 404 errors not detectable. The result is that many tests will return a successful match. This is a combination of poorly written detection rules in the nikto database which only check the response code and not text in the page or poorly matched keywords.

There isn't much you can do about this apart from using your brains and experience to filter out the results you know are wrong and check the ones that may be viable.

Due to many of these false positive rules belonging to older software it is difficult to create vulnerable installations to test on to update the rules and eliminate the false positives, however if you want to help, nikto is open source and accept pull requests.